# Add a button when image or video loads in a webview

Tags: android, webview, customization, addition

I want to add a button when image or video loads in a WebView. Like this in Images given below.

[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJFOP.png)

[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD2Hc.png)

Comment: You can used frame layout to overlap  download button with webview

Comment: Please give some example if you can?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @M.Farhanulkarim You got any solution of that ? I also want some help on this. Did found any solution for the same and parsing video urls of different video quality ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

add drawable as per your need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_more"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_download"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/webView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65999997"
     
        app:tint="@color/white"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: this code will add a button on fixed position of webview and will always shows.... i want to add a button when image  or video is loaded.

Comment: please check this app  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=free.video.downloader.freevideodownloader.

Comment: you need to play with visibility from code